# Pulling data that falls between date range in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

On the front end of my application I have created a drop down. I want the dropdown to contain a selection list of all the available fiscal year dates a user can choose from. To do this I have 2 tables.

The product table which has an awarded date column:

```
+--------------+
| AwardedDate |
+--------------+
| 2021-01-07   |
| 2023-01-07   |
| 2026-07-19   |
+--------------+
```

And the FiscalYear table which has 3 columns of note:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Name | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+------+------------+------------+
| FY15 | 2014-10-01 | 2015-09-30 |
| FY16 | 2015-10-01 | 2016-09-30 |
| FY17 | 2016-10-01 | 2017-09-30 |
| ...  | ...        | ...        |
+------+------------+------------+
```

I want to write a query that looks up my products by their awardedDate and then uses the StartDate and EndDate of my fiscal years table to return the appropriate fiscal year name.

For example, if my awarded date is 2016-11-27 the query should return the FY17

I am new to SQL and tried something like this:

```
SELECT fy.Name
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN FiscalYears fy ON
```

But I do not know how to compare dates yet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN`:

```
select p.*, fy.NAME
from Products p
    left join FiscalYear fy ON p.AwardedDate between fy.StartDate and fy.EndDate
```